# converting pine script to python

Tags: python, pine-script

i am converting the following pine script to python.
the python code works good but the last part of code which detects the `dir/direction` doesn't work.

```
//@version=4
study("STrend", overlay=true)

length = input(title="ATR Period", type=input.integer, defval=22)
mult = input(title="ATR Multiplier", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=3)
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=hl2)
wicks = input(title="Take Wicks into Account ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
showLabels = input(title="Show Buy/Sell Labels ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
highlightState = input(title="Highlight State ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)

atr = mult * atr(length)
highPrice = wicks ? high : close
lowPrice = wicks ? low : close
doji4price = open == close and open == low and open == high

longStop = src - atr
longStopPrev = nz(longStop[1], longStop)
if longStop > 0
    if doji4price
        longStop := longStopPrev
    else
        longStop := (lowPrice[1] > longStopPrev ? max(longStop, longStopPrev) : longStop)
else
    longStop := longStopPrev
    

shortStop = src + atr
shortStopPrev = nz(shortStop[1], shortStop)
if shortStop > 0
    if doji4price
        shortStop := shortStopPrev
    else
        shortStop := (highPrice[1] < shortStopPrev ? min(shortStop, shortStopPrev) : shortStop)
else
    shortStop := shortStopPrev
    
    
var int dir = 1
dir :=
         dir == -1 and highPrice > shortStopPrev ? 1 :
         dir == 1 and lowPrice < longStopPrev ? -1 :
         dir

plot(longStop, color=color.green)
plot(shortStop, color=color.red)
plotshape(dir == 1 ? dir: na, color=color.green)
plotshape(dir == -1 ? dir: na, color=color.red)
```

here is the python code which is converted from the above pine-script.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta
import yfinance as yf


plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")

df = yf.download("TSLA", start="2023-01-01")
print(df.head())

length = 22
mult = 3
df["hl2"] = (df["High"] + df["Low"]) / 2
src = df["hl2"]
atr = mult * ta.atr(df["High"], df["Low"], df["Close"], length=length)
doji4price = (
    (df["Open"] == df["Close"]) & (df["Open"] == df["Low"]) & (df["Open"] == df["High"])
)

long_stop = src - atr
long_stop_prev = long_stop.shift(1).fillna(long_stop)
for i in range(1, len(long_stop)):
    if long_stop[i] > 0:
        if doji4price[i]:
            long_stop[i] = long_stop_prev[i]
        else:
            long_stop[i] = (
                max(long_stop[i], long_stop_prev[i])
                if df["Low"][i - 1] > long_stop_prev[i]
                else long_stop[i]
            )
    else:
        long_stop[i] = long_stop_prev[i]


short_stop = src + atr
short_stop_prev = short_stop.shift(1).fillna(short_stop)
for i in range(1, len(short_stop)):
    if short_stop[i] > 0:
        if doji4price[i]:
            short_stop[i] = short_stop_prev[i]
        else:
            short_stop[i] = (
                min(short_stop[i], short_stop_prev[i])
                if df["High"][i - 1] < short_stop_prev[i]
                else short_stop[i]
            )
    else:
        short_stop[i] = short_stop_prev[i]

d = 1
direction = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if d == -1 and df["High"][i] > short_stop_prev[i]:
        d = 1
        direction.append(1)
    elif d == 1 and df["Low"][i] < long_stop_prev[i]:
        d = -1
        direction.append(-1)
    else:
        d = d
        direction.append(d)

direction = pd.Series(direction)
direction.index = df.index


plt.plot(df["Close"], color="cyan")
plt.plot(long_stop, color="green")
plt.plot(short_stop, color="red")
plt.plot(df["Close"][direction == 1], "^", color="darkgreen")
plt.plot(df["Close"][direction == -1], "v", color="darkred")
plt.legend(["close", "long stop", "short stop", "^", "v"])
plt.show()
```

here is the **problem**; the output of following python code is not same as the output of following pine script.
from the month 1 to 7 the `else` part of the python code is executed which is wrong. look at the python plot and tradingview plot, the `direction` in python is not equal to the `dir`.

```
dir :=
         dir == -1 and highPrice > shortStopPrev ? 1 :
         dir == 1 and lowPrice < longStopPrev ? -1 :
         dir
```

the python code in the below was written from the above pine-script but it's not doing the same thing.
what's wrong with this part of the code?

```py
d = 1
direction = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if d == -1 and df["High"][i] > short_stop_prev[i]:
        d = 1
        direction.append(1)
    elif d == 1 and df["Low"][i] < long_stop_prev[i]:
        d = -1
        direction.append(-1)
    else:
        d = d
        direction.append(d)
```

here is the plot of python code.

[image: output of python code]

and here is the plot of the tradingview pine script. the green line is `longStop` variable, red line is `shortStop`, `green x` is `dir == 1` shows uptrend and `red x` shows downtrend `dir == -1`. the blue line is the `close` price.

[image: output of pine-script]

Comment: I don't think this issue be related to your `else` or your conditions, I think you have a problem in your `variables`... please check your code properly before you post that